# How to get rids of nuget packages which is OK to delete. (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

Everytime when I update XF or Platforms, some built-in nugets are appeared in my nuget Packages list.

For example, System.Collections, System.Diagnostics.Debug, System.Linq and many many.
These kind of things were not in the nuget Packges list before. But I thought it's necessary.

And I noticed that package list of XF project just created are very clean.
It does not seems a big problem but it's annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin Forms won't add in these packages, but you likely have other packages that do. I am assuming you are using.NET Standard. Normally .NET Standard NuGet packages reference these types of packages.

As for your question, it won't affect the XF packages at all, but may affect other packages you might be using.

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks again. I didn't try to think that way. By the way, I'm using .NET PCL. (Please let me know if using .NET standard has benefit) But still, It's annoying that I had to see those many lists of regular nuget packages. So, what you meant is that it's natural and I don't have to care about?

Comment: .NET Standard is the future, making it easier to support more platforms, without recompiling each time you need to support a new platform. Its great for framework developers, which is why everyone is switching to it. Profile Based PCL's are officially on their way out, so the change is coming whether people want it or not. :) I know it has a bit of a learning curve and issues here and there, but its better to just dive in and get used to it for any new projects.

Comment: Wow. Thanks again!